# Phonegap (Cordova) iOS button click

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to create a very simple phone gap application for iOS. I am using query mobile. the problem is, that i can't get javascript event to fire on button click.
Code i have now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
        }

        function showAlert() {
            navigator.notification.alert("Cordova is working");
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="options" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Atgal">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <h1>Alert</h1>
            <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;" data-role="button">Show alert</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried multiple solutions to fix my problem, but none of them works. When have button with # in href, it doesn't event change the color on click. When i add url, it changes color. But it never call javascript function.
Another problem is, that `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` works only in the index page. If i press button in initial page which redirects to another page, OnDeviceReady function is never called.
Anybody has any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onDeviceReady()` is only called once (when the device (ie Cordova) is ready). You'll want `$(document).on('pageinit', '#pageid', function() { });` for something to fire every time the page is navigated to.

Comment: Don't know why, but this doesn't work too. Even $(document).ready is not helping.

Answer (score 2):

In the body tag you need to add  tag and the onBodyLoad() function in the javascript should be like:

```
   function onBodyLoad()
    {       
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a total noob with phone gap and query mobile, so i made a stupid mistake. Problem is, that it loads not whole page, when i click on button, but only body part. This means, that it uses only javascript which is in the first page. And that was my problem. Now i have putted all javascript into separate file (all javascript for both files) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
        }

        function showAlert() {
            navigator.notification.alert("Cordova is working");
        }

        $(function() {
            $("#my_link").click(function() {
                showAlert();
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="options" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Atgal">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <h1>Alert</h1>
            <p><a id="my_link" href="#" data-role="button">Show alert</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps. Let me know about your results.

Comment: i tried this: `<p><a href="javascript:showAlert()" data-role="button">Atnaujinti</a></p>`. Button looks like working (changing color on click), but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Even though i had z-index set higher for the md-button it still wouldn't click on iOS.  It clicked fine on Android.  I had to set a parent container in my case the `<md-subheader>` to z-index: -1; then it worked.